# Benefit Symfony/Twig i18n from VueJs component

Tags: symfony, twig, vuejs2

I use Symfony3 with Twig template and VueJs 2.

My symfony controller returns a Twig view with Articles component :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <Articles></Articles>
{% endblock %}
```

And my Articles.vue component :

```
<template>
    <section class="articleapp">
        <header>
            <h1>Mes articles</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="main">
                <li class="article" v-for="article in articles">
                    {{ article.title }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                articles: [{title: "Voici le nom d'un article"}]
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I would like translate my title "`Mes articles`" with Sf/Twig i18n like `{{ "Mes articles"|trans({}, "") }}` to benefit of translate catalogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Single page component it's impossible.

But with [X-Template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#X-Templates), the problem can be resolve :

index.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ "Mes posts"|trans({}, 'app') }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="app">
        <post-form></post-form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block components %}
    {{ include("components/form.html.twig", {"form": form }) }}
{% endblock %}
```

components/form.html.twig :

```
    <script id="post-form-template" type="text/x-template">
        <div>
            {{ "Mon formulaire"|trans({}, '') }}
            {{ form(form) }}
            <h1>${ greetings }</h1>
        </div>
    </script>
```

And my app.js :

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueResource from "vue-resource"

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.component('post-form', {
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    template: '#post-form-template',
    data: function () {
        return {
            greetings: 'Hello'
        };
    }
});

new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    el: "#app"
});
```